# matlab: zero loop in neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-network

everyone! I wanna have neural network with loop. I create neural network

```
net = newff(rand(5, 100), rand(1, 100), [3, 2], { 'tansig' 'tansig'}, 'traingdx3', 'learngdm', 'mse');
net.layerConnect(1, 1) = 1;
net.layerWeights{1, 1}.delays = [1];

net.trainParam.epochs = 100;

net = train(net, rand(5, 100), rand(1, 100));
```

and

```
net.LW

ans = 

    [3x3 double]              []    []
    [2x3 double]              []    []
              []    [1x2 double]    []
```

but when I view `net.LW{1, 1}` , I get

```
net.LW{1, 1}

ans =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
```

why loop weights always zeros?

Comment: sorry `'traingdx'` instead of `'traingdx3'`

Comment: *1.* Make the correction in your question. *2.* What do you think should you be getting and why?

Comment: Sorry for late post. I think I should get non-zero `net.LW{1, 1}` . The same zero weights appear when i try connect another layers.